# How to get All Active Categories in Custom Module Admin Form(UI-component) Dropdown in Magento 2?

Tags: category, collection, magento2.2.2, ui-form

I need to get all categories in a dropdown in admin ui form. So Please provide me a solution

**Form.xml**

```
<field name="category_name" sortOrder="10" formElement="select">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">

                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">namespace\xxx\Model\Sources\Categories</item>               
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">           
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">category_name</item>          
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>string</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Category Name</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
```

Comment: Can You Post the code of you admin form.@Sri

Comment: Please see the above post and provide me a solution @Pranay K

Comment: Are you getting empty field value.@Sri

Comment: I din't get the collection using the above code

Comment: I will try and post the answer @Sri

Comment: I got the category collection

Answer (score 2):

File Path Of Your Ui_component File would be

File Path :**/app/code/YourModuleExtension/YourModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/your_file_form.xml**

```
<field name="admin_category_form_field">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">\YourModuleExtension\YourModuleName\Model\FileName.php</item>
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Field Label</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">FieldName</item>
                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">admin_category_form_field</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
```

**File Path :\YourModuleExtension\YourModuleName\Model\FileName.php**

You can Also Put Below Code in Following File

```
<?php

namespace \YourModuleExtension\YourModuleName\Model\Sources;

class Categories implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    protected $_categories;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collection,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    )
    {
        $this->_categories = $collection;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {   

    $categories = $this->_categories->create();
    $collection = $categories->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
    $itemArray = array('value' => '', 'label' => '--Please Select--');
        //
        $categoryArray = array();
        $categoryArray[] = $itemArray;
        foreach ($collection as $category)
        {       
            $categoryArray[] = array('value' => $category->getId(), 'label' => $category->getName());

        }
        return $categoryArray;
}
}


?>
```

Comment: I need to get name of the categoreies

Comment: Please See the above post and provide me a solution

Answer (score 2):

I got the category collection in a dropdown field in ui component form using below code

```
class Categories implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{

    protected $_categories;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $collection)
    {
        $this->_categories = $collection;
    }

    public function toOptionArray()
    {

        $collection = $this->_categories->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        $itemArray = array('value' => '', 'label' => '--Please Select--');
        $options = [];
        $options = $itemArray;
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            $options[] = ['value' => $category->getId(), 'label' => $category->getName()];
        }
        return $options;
    }

}
```

Comment: Congrts, Gud Job.Thanks For sharing the answers. @Sri