# Dropdown in admin form

Tags: magento2.2, uicomponent, php-7, ui-form

I have created some category using admin ui-component form and displayed in ui-component grid.

Also i want created a drop down field(Field name: Parent category) in this form which contains already created categories list ...

[image]

How to do this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following code.

```
protected $category;
protected $categoryRepository;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $category,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->category = $category;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }
```

add below code into your function or in execute method

```
$categories = $this->category->getStoreCategories();
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            echo $category->getName();
            //$categoryObj = $this->categoryRepository->get($category->getId());

        }
```

follow this [link](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-parent-category-children-categories-product-count/) for more details

and refer to this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219535/how-to-get-all-active-categories-in-custom-module-admin-formui-component-dropd) too

Comment: Thanks .. But  i want to create a dropdown above mentioned model